# How to start Animation immediately after onCreate?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am following http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#frame-animation with minor changes. I have decided to make the animation loop and want it to start from the get-go.

My animation is at drawable/listening.xml:

```
<animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/l_01"
    android:duration="200" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/l_02"
    android:duration="200" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/l_03"
    android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

and my init code:

```
 @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)  { 
      super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus); 
      animImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.listen_anim);
      animImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listening);
      anim = (AnimationDrawable) animImg.getBackground(); 
      anim.start();
 };
```

All I see is the first frame and no other images.

Comment: If you followed it to the letter, than why is your start() call inside the init and not inside onTouchEvent?

Comment: You have put that init code exactly as advised in the tutorial? "It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window."

Comment: Ok, but I want the animation to start on load not on touch, how to accomplish?

Answer (score -18, accepted):

Run this in onResume():

```
class AnimTask extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {
            Activity act;
            AnimTask(Activity act) {
                this.act = act;
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){
                        animImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.listen_anim);
                        animImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listening);
                        anim = (AnimationDrawable) animImg.getBackground();
                        anim.start();
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whoever -1 this better have an explanation

Comment: I don't know who put it that negative but this code has serious problems, you NEVER update UI objecst outside UI thread.  Check that doInBackground(), is executed OUTSIDE UI thread.

Comment: The problem when you attempt to run the thread directly inside the activity is that it complains that it is not run on the UI thread. If you simply try to start the anim in onResume, nothing happens, I suppose slightly cleaner is to create a Thread in onResume and call Activity.this.runOnUiThread() , and so I don't believe you have a point sir.

Comment: The point is that this code IS WRONG and you don't properly read android documentation. Stackoverflow is not a contest on who knows better what, this site is all about helping others, at least that's the way I'm using it and I have learned many things in here. So next time have more consideration with people that waste his/her own valuable time to help you.

Comment: It works but it's a hacky solution. You're creating a race condition by hoping that the activity has finished setting up before the background thread runs. It may run on devices, but there is no guarantee that something won't change in future versions of android and the race condition will cause it to start failing.

Comment: The "better" implementation of this would be to post to a view: `myView.post(new Runnable() { ... });`

Answer (score 51):

It's already written in the tutorial:

*It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window.*

***If you want to play the animation immediately, without requiring interaction**, then you might want to call it from the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity, which will get called when Android brings your window into focus.*

So move your call to start in one of those two places, depending on your wish. Based on your comment, move your call to start inside **onWindowsFocusChanged()**.

**EDIT**
So this is *"How to do it"*:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        textView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left|android.R.anim.fade_in));
    }   
}
```

The points to pay attention to are:

- do not forget to write the if/else case to check the focus
- and delete the auto-generated **"super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);**"

Comment: This fails: @Override 
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  animImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.listen_anim);
  animImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listening);
  anim = (AnimationDrawable) animImg.getBackground();
  anim.start(); 
  
 };

Comment: Also, be nice. If I take the time to edit your question and tags, it's in the interest of others who might make the same mistake. How does your override "fail" exactly?

Comment: Based on the tutorial, again, I'd advise you to put the declarations inside onCreate and only the call to start inside onWindowsFocusChanged

Comment: Well, if it suits you, you've solved your issue. Launching a special thread just for setting up the animation seems a bit over the top to me, but you might have some good reason to do so that you're withholding.

Comment: There is no other solution I've found and all the conversations on stackoverflow and on Android say that a new thread is required.

Comment: Works for me and is pretty simple to implement. +1

Comment: How about fragment? There's no onWindowFocusChanged() in a fragment.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If the animation target object is a EditText type, once you click on it the animation will restart again, any idea for that?

Comment: @MarticZtn Can't you use a boolean flag?

Comment: @Kheldar I figured it out later, I created an integer and it will increase the count for every focus, then I just used an if statement to check if the focusCount is less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 9):

Have a flag set in `onAttachedToWindow()`  and then in `onWindowFocusChanged()` check it and start the animation.

```
@Override
void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus & mbFlag) {
        // start animation.
    }
}
```

### Update

Simply extend the `ImageView` class and override `onFocusChange` method. Then in your activity set the focus to it by calling `animImg.requestFocus()`. The animation should start when it gets focused. Make sure your imageview is focusable.

If this does not work, you may want to override the `onAttachedToWindow()` method also. Set a flag in there and check before starting the animation.

```
@Override
void onFocusChange(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        // start animation.
    }
}
```

Comment: which view's onAttachedToWindow do you recommend?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `post` method of any `View` on the activity. It should probably look like this:

```
View anyView = findViewById(R.id.anyView);
anyView.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give time to UI manager create appropiate resources BEFORE starting animation. Correct pattern is

```
a) Create animation object in onCreate.
b) Start animation object elsewhere.
```

Don't create and start in same method.

Comment: Yes ruhalde, see our discussion and his solution where we have pointed this out.

Comment: Ok, but nobody explains why you have to do it that way Is all about single threading model of Android, while your code is executing UI manager is not working, that's why you should create in OnCreate then exit (UI manager create proper resources) and then you do Start() in your code and exit again (UI manager stat animation).

Answer (score 0):

As this question was asked some long time ago, I have encounter same problem in 2019 with usage of transitions-Everywhere or AndroidX Transitions. 
And the only solution for me was to use @Muzikant answer. 
Simply call in your `onCreate()`

```
rootViewOfYourLayout.post {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootViewOfYourLayout)
            someViewId.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
```

And it works perfectly, for example in my case for Splash screen.

**Update**
 As after some testing, it appears this solution has minor issue. Animation is started and you block the phone or move app to background, and in result when app again in foreground it's just frozen as no TransitionListener callbacks received, so in my case onTransitionEnd() wasn't called where was located logic to navigate user to next screen.

For now this works for me without problems :

```
  override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
   if(hasFocus && isAnimationStarted.not()){
   rootViewOfYourLayout.post {
          TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootViewOfYourLayout)
          someViewId.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out);

yourobject.startanimation(animation);
```

This may help