# Start an animation automatically without the need of click on screen

Tags: android, animation

i know this question has been asked many times before but i could never quite understand as the other codes were quite a bit more complex or different than mine. so like the question says ... how to start animation automatically instead of on click .. ill leave the code below ... thanks in advance.. !!

```
         final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.animation);
         a.reset();
         final ImageView rImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title);

         RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
         layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override public void onClick(View v) {
         rImage.startAnimation(a);
         func(); //A call to the function.

         }
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work... This will be triggered everytime the activity is "displayed".

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // layout should have bee initialized in onCreate
    layout.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            rImage.startAnimation(a);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put  your code in onResume, or onCreate depends of your needs, also you can set a timer to active this code, there are many ways...

[How to start Animation immediately after onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289827/how-to-start-animation-immediately-after-oncreate)
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/start-animation-in-oncreate-or-onresume-on-android/