# onCreate Animation not working

Tags: java, android

I have an animation on my main screen and it shows up when the app starts.

I added an animation in onCreate method.

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);
    Animation animButtonEnter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.button_enter);
    exit.startAnimation(animButtonEnter);
}
```

button_enter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:duration="700"/>

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:duration="500"/>

<translate
    android:fromYDelta="200%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:duration="700"/>
```

I tried this but the animation didn't work.

I search about this but it says I have to use onWindowFocusChanged method.

Do I have to use onWindowFocusChanged method to do this?

I want to use onCreate method for this code.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: post button_enter animation file

Comment: animation should be ideally started on *onWindowFocusChanged* method try it once

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak The xml file have no problem with this. I use the animation xml on another animation and it works. But, I will post it. :)

Comment: @IllegalArgument Do I must use onWindowFocusChanged method for start up animation?

Comment: @BedrockDev read this answer and also the documentation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289827/how-to-start-animation-immediately-after-oncreate there are workarounds but why go the long way

Comment: @Apurva I did, but it didn't work onResume method :(

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Animation animButtonEnter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.button_enter);
```

To

```
Animation animButtonEnter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.button_enter);
```